# Python: List comprehension with if else statement not working as expected

Tags: python, list, class, if-statement, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert a code block into list comprehension but it is throwing an error.

Below is what my class looks like:

```
class Customer:
    c_id = None
    
    def __init__(self, cid):
        self.c_id = cid
```

I have created 2 objects from the above class. Both these objects are stored in a list.

```
a = Customer(1)
b = Customer(2)

lst = [a,b]
```

Further, I have written a get_id function that will either take an object or list as the input and will return a list of ids.

```
# Ver 1
def get_ids_v1(obj):
    return [obj.c_id if not isinstance(obj, list) else cust.c_id for cust in obj]

# Ver 2
def get_ids_v2(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [cust.c_id for cust in obj]
    else:
        return [obj.c_id]
```

Now, when I am passing the obj / list through the ver 2 fuction, it is working fine.

```
get_ids_v2(a)
Out: [1]

get_ids_v2(lst)
Out: [1, 2]
```

The Ver 1 function works well with the list, but throws an error on passing the obj.

```
get_ids_v1(lst)
Out: [1, 2]

get_ids_v1(a)
Out: TypeError: 'Customer' object is not iterable
```

I do not understand what is going wrong here.
when I tried implementing something similar, it worked for me (see below):

```
def get_id(obj):
    return [obj["id"] if not isinstance(obj, list) else cust["id"] for cust in obj]

c = {"id":3}
d = [{"id":4}, {"id":5}]

get_id(c)
Out: [3]

get_id(d)
Out: [4, 5]
```

Comment: the list comprehension iterates over the paramter, `for cust in obj`. But `obj` is a `Customer` object, which is not iterable (as the error message explains)

Comment: Right.  You can fix this with parentheses: `return [obj.c_id if not isinstance(obj, list) else (cust.c_id for cust in obj)]` works as you expect.  Comprehensions are parsed from the outside in.

Comment: @TimRoberts mmm that would create a list with a single element which is either `obj.c_id` or a generator object, I don't think that is what the OP expets

Comment: Note, your `get_id` works because both a dict and a list are iterable. However, it is pretty confusing, and I would not let that pass code review where I work.

Comment: @PrathameshPavnoji why must this be a list comprehension? `get_ids_v2` is perfectly reasonable and pythonic.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the snippets I posted on top belong to a single function which I want to reduce in size. It contains several other conditional blocks.

Comment: then *refactor that part it into its own function* and call it in the other function.

Comment: In this case, you would need something like `[cust.id for cust in (obj if isinstnace(obj, list) else (obj,))]` but seriously, *don't do that*. That's terribly unclean code

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! I'll try incorporating these suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check if the argument is iterable *after* trying to iterate over it. You *could* do something like:

```
return [cust.c_id for cust in (obj if isinstance(obj, list) else (obj,))]
```

But that's pretty unclean and unreadable. At the very least, do:

```
obj = obj if isinstance(obj, list) else (obj,)
return [cust.c_id for cust in obj]
```

But really, your code in `get_ids_v2` is **perfectly fine and pythonic**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the parameter type outside of the comprehension and return the c_id directly from obj if it is not a list:

```
def get_ids_v1(obj):
    return [cust.c_id for cust in obj] if isinstance(obj,list) else obj.c_id
```

Alternatively you could change the source of the iteration:

```
def get_ids_v3(obj):
    return [ o.c_id for o in ([obj],obj)[isinstance(obj, list)] ]
```